# Question on Stack Overflow not getting answered?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, not-an-answer

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588188/trying-to-communicate-from-default-script-to-content-script-in-chrome-extension) on Stack Overflow figuring it was fairly easy and simple, expecting an answer within the next day or two, I went about my own little world.

I managed to get 2 answers. The fact is, neither of them worked, I commented and got a little response, but not much, now I'm stuck with a question, buried far underneath all the new more high-priority questions.

I never upvoted nor marked either as the best answer, I edited the question to show this in hopes someone would see an answer.

As you can probably tell I do not have enough rep to offer a bounty, I cannot duplicate the question as it's against rules, I cannot answer it myself as I do not know the answer, what should I do?

What does a user normally do when facing a similar situation?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't ask a question and then run away.  You should stick around and provide feedback.

Comment: I did though, I did check in and provide feedback when I had the chance.

Comment: AstroCB, thanks for the edit, I added a space in upvote and took it out of Stack Overflow (fail)

Comment: You provided feedback *several days* later.

Comment: What? I haven't even been on the site for a freaking month? What do you mean?

Comment: @warspyking Relax- Servy made a mistake and edited. Still, from the looks of it, you did wait a few days before saying the answers didn't work or commenting about them. That could be your problem.

Comment: Okay just saw your edit, I had commented within a few hours of posting, and I had commented back to people as soon as I got the chance, it is not my fault I am busy.

Comment: @warspyking So long as this project you're working on isn't in a time crunch, I wouldn't worry too much- A bounty has been added to your post by a generous contributor, and in a couple days you should have more attention, between that and your post here. :)

Comment: Hi @warspyking, there's actually another Meta site for Stack Exchange in general, and it may provide you with better assistance for this kind of thing. For example, there is this question from the meta FAQ: [How do I get attention for unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/158605), or this one if you don't have rep for bounties [How to draw attention to a question without creating a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16874/158605)

Comment: Besides, I had replied back but they did not, so how can I get an answer now? A duplicate is not allowed.

Comment: Engagement is actually very important. When you post a question or an answer, you better stick around (for a few hours) long enough to "finish what you started". If you don't there's a good chance everyone is just gonna go away and not care anymore. If you're not willing to stick around, don't post yet.

Comment: @Kendra That's awesome :D who is this "generous contributer"?

Comment: @Rachel Thanks I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @warspyking If you look, there's a box just under your question mentioning the bounty, where it gives the reason, the amount, and the bounty offerer.

Comment: Might I also suggest removing the line at the top of your SO post about a bounty? It's unnecessary fluff, especially now that there is one.

Comment: @Kendra Alright I'll look, I was taking a look at Rachel's link, in which the answer says edit the question (been there done that)

Comment: @Kendra I know, I will now, I was just stressing the fact that it wasn't answered

Comment: @warspyking Great- And good luck in getting your answer. I'm sure between here and the bounty, you'll have one within a week now.

Comment: @warspyking I edited my first comment to add a second link for how to draw attention to a question without creating a bounty :)

Comment: @Kendra Alright I removed the "fluff" and I hope I'll get an answer, thanks! And thanks to the person who set up the bounty, it was greatly appreciated :D

Comment: One problem is the quality of your question. I have almost no idea what you're asking for. You can't just dump code and say to fix it...

Comment: In addition, it appears to be a [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @Servy You cannot expect users to stay around and give up their entire life _waiting for you to respond to a question or comment_ just as you expect us to not get the shits if nobody answers or comments right away [for the same reason].

Comment: @Jase Actually you can.  There *is* an expectation that those asking questions will stay active for at least some amount of time after asking their question to respond to clarifying questions and comments.  Not doing so *dramatically* reduces the odds of the question being answerable, or of it getting a correct answer.  The OP was upset at a bunch of people not understanding his question, which is a direct result of him *not answering clarifying questions asked by others*.